# Form doesn't submit

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html

I'm coding a web app with MEAN, and I don't understand the way to validate a form with Angular and pass the info to Node to register or login an user.

Here's my jade code

```
html(ng-app="modulo")
...
body#page-top.index(ng-controller="mainController")
...
div
  a.btn.btn-default(ng-click="ShowForm()")
    span.fa.fa-user
    |  Local Login

  a.btn.btn-default(href='/signup')
    span.fa.fa-user
    |  Local Signup
  |         
  a.btn.btn-primary(href='/auth/facebook')
    span.fa.fa-facebook
    |  Facebook
  |            
  a.btn.btn-danger(href='/auth/google')
    span.fa.fa-google-plus
    |  Google+

    form(name="submit_form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-show="formVisibility")
      div.form-group
        label Email
        input(type="text" name="email").form-control
      div.form-group
        label Password
        input(type="password" name="password").form-control
      button(type="submit").btn.btn-warning.btn-lg
        | Login
```

And my Angular controller

```
var modulo = angular.module('modulo', []);

modulo.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.message = 'Hello World!'

    $scope.formVisibility = false;

    $scope.ShowForm = function(){
        $scope.formVisibility = true;
    }

    $scope.submit = function(){
        if($scope.submit_form.$valid)
            alert("Nuestro formulario es guay");
    }}]);
```

When I press the submit button the app show the alert but Node doesn't works so I can't access to the web.

What I have to add to make local login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we generally create single page apps with Angular, we don't want the browser to automatically submit the form. If it did, it would cause a full page load with the server response, "breaking" the single page app functionality.

You have to write code to submit the form and its data (using `$http` or `$resource`). I assume your `submit()` function is getting called, so the next step is to POST (or whatever) the data:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  if ($scope.submit_form.$valid) {
    // inject $http into your controller
    $http.post('/some/url', myFormData);
  }
}
```

PS: If you want the browser to submit the form, just add the `action` attribute to the `<form>` tag. Angular will see that and let the browser submit the form.

Comment: Hello, I did it. But the web keep doing nothing. In the terminal I have a request and a response of the server with /login (I like to run this function) but the website have not change

Comment: Just as you have to write the code to send the request, you have to write the code to process the response. You might want to look at the examples/documentation for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).  When you do `$http.post()` it returns a `$promise`. You can see in the example, that they are using the promise's `success()` function to handle a successful server response.

Comment: I use a simple callback (show a text in terminal) with the promise, but the web keep without login :(

Comment: If you are making a single page app, your code should look at the server response to see if the login attempt was successful. If it was, then your code should change the view so they can use your app. If you're not making a single page app (and just trying to use Angular on your login page), then you need to do what I said in the "PS" above.